# Why does Jquery FullCalendar Not specify an end date as a title when it is 12:00:00AM?

Tags: time, fullcalendar, date

I am getting this data back in a valid json feed.

```
"start":"10/16/2011 11:00:00 PM","end":"10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM"
```

My event on the calendar will have

11:00am in the title part but nothing else

[image: full calendar]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/aa34110374367a8e8cf29a4fdf179c13.png))</sub>

I am not sure why it is ignoring it.

If I do say 11:59 am it works

[image: full calendar]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/ce4eee4774a47ea14732db4c93b4c4ef.png))</sub>

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end time 12:00 AM is less than the start time 11:00 PM. So you are having the problem.
12:00 AM would mean the start of the day :)

Comment: I see what your saying but I expected it to show 12:00 Am  even if it goes to the next day. It also messes with the dragging. If I drag that to a different time slot it will only show the start time no end time. Is there a way to get it to say 12:00 AM. I think it would make things simpler.

Comment: @chobo2 What he's saying is `"start":"10/16/2011 11:00:00 PM","end":"10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM"` should be `"start":"10/16/2011 11:00:00 PM","end":"10/17/2011 12:00:00 AM"`